# Problema formato JSON

Tags: php, laravel, json, array

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Laravel 7, es una tienda on line. Para sincronizar la tienda con el catálogo de productos, stocks, etc, hago uso de la API que facilita el proveedor. Hasta ahora todo va bien, pero tengo un problema a la hora de hacer la petición a la url que crea una nueva orden(pedido). Debo enviar un json con el siguiente formato:

```
 {
  "order": {
    "internalReference": "123456",
    "language": "es",
    "paymentMethod": "moneybox",
    "carriers": [
      {
        "name": "correos"
      },
    ],
    "shippingAddress": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "country": "ES",
      "postcode": "46005",
      "town": "Valencia",
      "address": "C/ Altea",
      "phone": "664869570",
      "email": "john@email.com",
      "comment": ""
    },
    "products": [
      {
        "reference": "V0100100",
        "quantity": 1,
        "internalReference": "LO5632"
      },
      {
        "reference": "F1505138",
        "quantity": 4,
        "internalReference": "LA4289"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Por mucho que lo he intentado no consigo obtener el json con ese formato, lo he intentado de diferentes formas pero consigo esto:

```
    {
    "order": {
        "internalReference": "20201212003435",
        "language": "ES",
        "paymentMethod": "moneybox",
        "carriers": [
      {
        "name": "correos"
      }
    ],
    "shippingAddress": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "country": "ES",
        "postcode": "45005",
        "town": "Valencia",
        "address": "C/ Altea",
        "phone": "662458333",
        "email": "john@email.com",
        "vatNumber": "",
        "companyName": "",
        "comment": ""
      },
    "products": [
    {
        "reference": [
            "5fcf3cb6b690f",
            "5fd10ee71e004"
      ],
        "quantity": [
            "1",
            "1"
      ],
       "internalReference": [
           "5fcf3cb6b690f",
           "5fd10ee71e004"
      ]
    }
    ],
    "dateAdd": "2020-12-12"
    }
  }
```

A continuación os muestro el formulario desde donde obtengo los datos. He omitido todos los divs, estilos, etc para que sea más legible:

```
<form class="form-checkout" id="form" action="{{route('orderCreate')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
<input type="text" name="firstName"> 
<input type="text" name="lastName"> 
<input type="text" name="company" >
<input type="text" name="vatNumber"> 
<input type="text" name="address"> 
<input type="text" name="town"> 
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="text" name="phone">
  <table class="table-cart" >
     <thead>
       <tr>
        <th width="80%">Product name</th>
        <th width="5%">Price</th>
        <th width="5%">Quantity</th>
        <th width="10%">Total</th>
        <th hidden>Id</th>
        <th hidden>InternalRef</th>
       </tr>
         </thead>
           <tbody>
           @foreach($cart as $item)
             <tr>
               <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="{{$item->quantity}}"></td>
               <td>{{number_format($item->price * $item->quantity,2,",",".")}} {{ env('CURRENCY_SYMBOL') }}</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="reference[]" value="{{$item->id}}"></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="internalReference[]" value="{{$item->id}}"></td>
            </tr>
@endforeach
```

Haciendo un dd de los datos que obtengo del formulario:

```
  array:1 [▼
  "order" => array:7 [▼
    "internalReference" => "20201212122507"
    "language" => "ES"
    "paymentMethod" => "moneybox"
    "carriers" => array:1 [▶]
    "shippingAddress" => array:11 [▶]
    "products" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "reference" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "5fcf3cb6b690f"
          1 => "5fd10ee71e004"
        ]
        "quantity" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "1"
          1 => "1"
        ]
        "internalReference" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "5fcf3cb6b690f"
          1 => "5fd10ee71e004"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "dateAdd" => "2020-12-12"
  ]
]
```

Y este es el método del controlador:

```
public function createNewOrder(Request $request)
    {
        $order = array(
            "order"=> array(
                "internalReference"=>date('YmdHis'),
                "language"=>"ES",
                "paymentMethod" => "moneybox",
                "carriers"=>array(
                    [
                        'name'=>'correos'
                    ]
            ),
             "shippingAddress" => array(
                "firstName" => $request->firstName,
                "lastName"=>$request->lastName,
                "country"=>"ES",
                "postcode"=>$request->postcode,
                "town"=>$request->town,
                "address"=>$request->address,
                "phone"=>$request->phone,
                "email"=>$request->email,
                "vatNumber"=>$request->vatNumber,
                "companyName"=>$request->companyName,
                "comment" => ""
             ),
             "products"=>array(
                [
                    "reference"=> $request->reference,
                    "quantity"=>$request->quantity,
                    "internalReference"=>$request->internalReference
                ]
            ),
                "dateAdd"=>date('Y-m-d'),
                ),
             );
        return json_encode($order);
    }
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tendrías que mapear los productos o cambiar los nombres de los inputs. Lo que no entiendo es como llegas de esos inputs al array que muestras del `dd`

Comment: como menciona @porloscerrosΨ es importante indicar como armas el json, debes generar un objeto con las propiedades **reference, quantity y internalReference**. Y ese objeto meterlo en un array.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ gracias por tu tiempo, he editado la pregunta añadiendo el formulario y el controlador.

Comment: @DarkFrostnight, gracias por tu tiempo, he editadola pregunta.

Comment: El problema es que los datos de **$request->reference, $request->quantity y $request->internalReference** contienen un array, debes recorrerlos y armar un array nuevo con el formato correcto por fuera y luego asignarlo a **"products"=>$myArrayNuevo**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo más fácil ahí es que cambies el nombre de los inputs para obtener el arreglo directamente, sin tener que mapearlo en el controlador.
Por ejemplo, si haces el foreach de esta manera en la vista, tendrás en la variable `$key` el índice de cada item, agrupando así cada producto en el mismo índice. Luego le agregas otro índice con el nombre de cada campo:

```
@foreach($cart as $key => $item)
    <input type="text" name="products[{{$key}}][quantity]" value="{{$item->quantity}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="products[{{$key}}][reference]" value="{{$item->id}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="products[{{$key}}][internalReference]" value="{{$item->id}}"/>
@endforeach
```

Finalmente en el controlador directamente asignas el valor del input `products` al elemento correspondiente del array con el que vas a generar el json:

```
$order = array(
    //...
    "products" => $request->products
    //...
);
```

El resultado esperado para `$request->products` sería algo así:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "quantity" => "1"
    "reference" => "qwe"
    "internalReference" => "qwe"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "quantity" => "2"
    "reference" => "asd"
    "internalReference" => "asd"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "quantity" => "3"
    "reference" => "zxc"
    "internalReference" => "zxc"
  ]
]
```

Referencia: [¿Cómo creo arrays en un `<form>` de HTML?](https://www.php.net/manual/es/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).